# How do i change bi-us-rds-September text value in a file to bi-us-rds- + current date with september as month name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

i have a file which contains few lines of code

identifier           = "bi-us-rds-15september"

i have to change "bi-us-rds-15september" with "bi-us-rds-current date & current month " .
For example - "bi-us-rds-15september" with "bi-us-rds-18september .
I want to accomplish this using task shell script but i am not good with scripting .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the date format

```
$ identifier="bi-us-rds-`date +%d%B`"
$ echo $identifier
bi-us-rds-18September
```

I'd suggest maybe using https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-date-format-options-examples/

Also fyi your question is a bit unhelpful - I'd suggest next time at least offer your current script so we can be more precise with the assistance.

edit: removed the extra hyphen just so it matches your exact output required

edit: re: your comment...

```
$replace=Hi
$replacewith="Hey"
$ echo "Hi how are you?" | sed -e "s/$replace/$replacewith/g"
Hey how are you?
```

Comment: thanks for your reply .
i have a question -
it will find the value in the file identifier           = "bi-us-rds-value name" and whichever the value is output should be imput for the next sed statement - sed -i -e "s/1value-fetched earlier /$var/g" /root/terraform/test1

Comment: What's the question? It sounds like that's already in place and you want to stop having to edit the file to be a date and instead be got automatically - in which case just change that one line and not worry about the rest. And refer to it as $identifier in your sed as it's now a known variable

Comment: See my edit - I think that's a bit clearer than what I've written in this comment box due to formatting limitations @sambit

Comment: thanks for the script . i will check it out .
i also have written a script  it also worked .
var1=$(cat /root/terraform/test1 | awk -F"-" '{ print $NF}' | sed 's/"//g')
var2=$(date |awk '{print $3$2}')
sed -i -e "s/$var1/$var2/g" /root/terraform/test1

Comment: Ok good. Accept the answer then if it's solved the original question.

Comment: i have accepted your answer is correct for the question.